# from googleapiclient.discovery import build ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleclient'

Tags: python-3.x, module, pyinstaller, google-api-client

I am using Pycharm and venv, and when I run my code from pycharm it works perfectly. But as soon as I build a .exe file I get this error.

I already tried to:

- install pyinstaller in the venv and create .exe file
- install google-api-python-client using command line instead of in venv and tried to compile .exe

  ```
  pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
  pip install --force-reinstall google-api-python-client
  ```

None of this works and after checking 'site-packages' it does include googleapiclient. Please help.